# Automatically generated database requests

Tags: java, sql, database

How do you implement automatically generated database (let it be SQL) requests?

Let us have offline shop with filters:

[image]

The database is standalone offline.

SO if I want to filter items by **Price** the request would be something like:

```
select Snowboard.Name
from Snowboard
where Snowboard.Price between 400 and 600;
```

And if I filter by two characteristics e.g. **Price** from and **Camber**. There would be:

```
select s.Name, s.Camber
from Snowboard s
where s.Price between 400 and 600
and s.Camber in ('Rocker', 'Hybrid');
```

**The question is how could it be implemented in Java so that these requests are generated automatically from any combination of filters selected?**

Comment: You'll have to generate sql query string with StringBuilder/Buffer. Based on input that is sent by UI.

Comment: u have not worked with JDBC ?

Comment: You might want to look at proper implementations of `Faceted search` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321595/what-is-faceted-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick and dirty solution #1**

Generate a query at run time & make clever use of `WHERE 1=1` condition as the number of where clause are unknown. (This sample is in C# but works more or less the same with JAVA as well)

```
string sql= @"select Snowboard.Name
from Snowboard
where 1=1";
```

Now you can build your query based on the UI element selections like

```
string whereClause="";
if(yourCheckBoxPrice.Checked) 
{
    whereClause+= " AND Price BETWEEN "+ txtPriceFrom.Text + " AND "+ txtPriceTo.Text;
}

if(yourCheckBoxCamber.Checked)
{
    whereClause+= " AND Camber IN ("+ /* your list of values go here */ +")"; 
}

sql += whereClause;
```

**2nd Solution (Use SQL CASE)**

You can use SQL CASE inside your query for each where clause to check for nulls or specific values. But beware, dynamic SQL will make your code pretty messy & hard to read (Can be done via a stored procedure as well)

[SQL- CASE Statement](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html)

I advise you to use a stored procedure with a mix of both options 1 and 2. [Implementing Dynamic SQL Where Clause](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-a-dynamic-where-clause). Keep it simple and you are good to go.