# App Engine Search API (Document Search) - Multiple Languages

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-search-api

I have Documents that I'd like to make searchable in 3 different languages. Since I can have multiple fields with the same name/type, the following Document structure works (this is a simplified example).

```
document = search.Document(
    fields=[
      search.TextField(
        name="name",
        language="en",
        value="dog"),
      search.TextField(
        name="name",
        language="es",
        value="perro"),
      search.TextField(
        name="name",
        language="fr",
        value="chien")
    ]
  )
  index = search.Index("my_index")
  index.put(document)
```

Specifying the language helps Google tokenize the value of the `TextField`.

The following queries all work, each returning one result:

```
print index.search("name: dog")
print index.search("name: perro")
print index.search("name: chien")
```

Here is my question: **Can I restrict a search to only target fields with a specific language**?

The purpose is to avoid getting false positive results. Since each language uses the Arabic alphabet, it's possible that someone performing a full text search in Spanish may see English results that are not relevant.

Thank you.

Comment: calling google translate api for language detection and using result in query: `get_index(lang-detected).search(query)` or translating search term to stored data language and searching based on translation result

Answer (score 2):

You can use [facets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/faceted_search) to add fields to a document that don't actually appear in the document (metadata). These would indicate what languages appear in the document.

Document insertion:

```python
    index = search.Index("my_index")
    document = search.Document(
        fields=[
          search.TextField(
            name="name",
            language="en",
            value="dog"),
          search.TextField(
            name="name",
            language="es",
            value="perro"),
          search.TextField(
            name="name",
            language="fr",
            value="chien")
        ],
        facets=[
           search.AtomFacet(name='lang', value='en'),
           search.AtomFacet(name='lang', value='es'),
           search.AtomFacet(name='lang', value='fr'),
        ],
      )
    index.put(document)
    document = search.Document(
        fields=[
          search.TextField(
            name="name",
            language="es",
            value="gato"),
          search.TextField(
            name="name",
            language="fr",
            value="chat")
        ],
        facets=[
           # no english in this document so leave out lang='en'
           search.AtomFacet(name='lang', value='es'),
           search.AtomFacet(name='lang', value='fr'),
        ],
      )
    index.put(document)
```

Query:

```python
index = search.Index("my_index")
query = search.Query(
    '', # query all documents, cats and dogs.
    # filter docs by language facet
    facet_refinements=[
        search.FacetRefinement('lang', value='en'),
    ])

results = index.search(query)
for doc in results:
    result = {}
    for f in doc.fields:
        # filter fields by language
        if f.language == 'en':
            result[f.name] = f.value
    print result
```

Should print `{u'name': u'dog'}`.

Note that although we can fetch only *documents* that have english in them, we still have to filter out the *fields* in other languages in those documents. This why we iterate through the fields only adding those in english to `result`.

If you want to know more about the more general use case for faceted search, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5374688/1900169) gives a pretty good idea.

Comment: Turns out you need to use FacetRefinements instead of FacetRequests. The former is to select documents by facets the latter only gives you information on what facets are available.

Comment: document = search.Document(
  doc_id=str("1"),
  fields=[
    search.TextField(language="en", name="name", value="one"),
    search.TextField(language="es", name="name", value="uno")
  ])
index.put(document)
document = search.Document(
  doc_id=str("2"),
  fields=[
    search.TextField(language="en", name="name", value="uno"),
    search.TextField(language="es", name="name", value="one")
  ])
index.put(document)
index.search(search.Query(
  "name: one",
  facet_refinements=[
    search.FacetRefinement("lang", value="en")
  ]))

Comment: The above code is quite gross, but SO won't let me format it in the comment. It's a case where FacetRefinement returns zero results, despite having a match. Do you know why?

Comment: @user326502 that's because you didn't add a `facets` parameter (or accompanying `AtomFacet`s to your document).

Comment: When I add `AtomFacets` to my document, then query with a `FacetRefinement` of `lang="en"`, both documents are returned. Which isn't really what I'm looking for. I'm trying to filter out the documents where the field has a match, but the language does not.

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to search only the English fields, and none of the other ones.

Comment: @user326502 the idea is to put only AtomFacet(name='lang', value='en'), in documents where you have `TextField` with language='en'.

Comment: @user326502 I extended my example to provide clarification

Comment: Thanks. Each document will have all 3 of the same languages. I suppose I could add separate documents for each distinct language. That changes how I planned on assigning `doc_id` but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a separate index for each language.

Define a utility function for resolving the correct index for a given language:

```python
def get_index(lang):
   return search.Index("my_index_{}".format(lang))
```

Insert documents:

```python
document = search.Document(
    fields=[
      search.TextField(
        name="name",
        language="en",
        value="dog"),
    ])

get_index('en').put(document)

document = search.Document(
    fields=[
      search.TextField(
        name="name",
        language="fr",
        value="chien")
    ])

get_index('fr').put(document)
```

Query by language:

```python
query = search.Query(
    'name: chien')

results = get_index('fr').search(query)

for doc in results:
    print doc
```

Comment: I took a similar approach by using separate fields for each language, and then appending the language code to the search field name. That's my fallback approach, but I'm hoping to find a better solution here.